# Can't override Spree::Order class without breaking original tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spree

This is my second project with Spree. When working in the first one(1.0), I didn't run tests against Spree's implementation.

This time(Spree 3.0) I decided to maintain a structure to run Spree's tests against the host application, making changes when needed. I've copied over Spree's specs, which is actually recommended in the [guide](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/testing.html#testing-your-spree-application) and changed `spec_helper.rb` to load my app instead of test_app created by `bundle exec rake test_app`.

Everything was working fine, until I tried to override the `Spree::Order` class. The curious thing is that tests are breaking with the mere presence of `Spree::Order.class_eval`, even without anything inside it.

Whenever trying to create orders on tests, I'm getting `Spree::User expected, but got Spree::LegacyUser`. I haven't got any problems when using the development environment, though.

One might ask why those tests are using the `Spree::LegacyUser` instead of `Spree::User`, which is what I'm using in the host app. The reason is that a lot of tests mock `User::LegacyUser`. That dummy app created by that aforementioned task, also uses `LegacyUser`.

I can't think of anything that might be interfering when creating an order. Inside `Spree::Order` we can find the following code, which should be dealing with specific User types:

```
if Spree.user_class
  belongs_to :user, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
  belongs_to :approver, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
  belongs_to :canceler, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
else
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :created_by
  belongs_to :approver
  belongs_to :canceler
end
```

If I reopen `Spree::Order`(copying everything over) and perform all of the required modifications for my new features, all tests remain green.

I don't want to override the whole class because it carries a lot of responsibilities and it will be a pain to apply eventual fixes the community may create.

I'll be happy to provide more context if this is not enough. I understand it's kind of a burden to replicate this on your environment, so any tips are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I know this is a while ago, but when you say you 'copied over the Spree tests', what did you do? I don't see any spec folders to copy

Comment: I copied the spec folder from the spree original repo. Actually I symlinked it, but it's all the same. That allows me to run spree tests targeting my actual app.

Comment: Interesting, that's what I thought you meant but I don't see a spec folder in the root of the repo https://github.com/spree/spree , was that the one from core or one of the component gems? - Thanks for the info!